Simulation of type-1 error rate, and how to check type-2-error (rate)
With $H_{0}:\mu = 0$,
iter = 100
n = 500
# alpha, beta
a = .05 # b(0.5) = .95 (given in the question)

and $x{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0.5, \sigma)$, for arbitrary $\sigma{>}0$, we apply a statistical test to test $H_{0}$, and expect that

5 tests make a type-1 error, or
5 tests make a type-2 error, or
5 tests reject $H_{0}$?

These options are true/false statements. To check (1), I did
set.seed(1)
replicate(iter, t.test(rnorm(500, .5, 5))$p.value < a) |> sum()

## e.g. returns
# [1] 63

I noticed that the results are heavily dependent on the choice of $\sigma$, i.e. it is difficult to conclude something general for me. I think that neither (1.) nor (3.) are correct. How can one check (2.)?

Welcome to CV.  (1) Your code won't run as written.  Perhaps iter is intended to be iterations? (2) Please display the output and explain what specifically you do not understand.  (3) Neither 1., 2., nor 3. is a question, so what do you mean by "check (2.)?"

@whuber, thank you for the help. I have adapted my question.

Yes, I just saw that and deleted my comment. Is this homework? If so, can you share the full question as stated in your homework, if you haven't?

@J-J-J, adapted again. It's not homework in the classical sense. I am not a student. I work myself through notes I found--just interest. Unfortunately, there are no solutions to this one.

Let's ignore your simulation code for a moment. What do you think the comment b(0.5) = 0.95 means? I ask in order to understand where you're stuck, and give you an explanation (though I find that Jeremy Miles' answer is good, it seems you're still stuck).

@J-J-J, you are right. Still stuck in deciding which, if any, statement is true. That is how the question defines beta. The value in the parenthesis is not specified any further.

$\beta$ could be completely different, it doesn't have to be 0.95 just because $\alpha=0.05$. However, to complicate things and unless I'm missing something, it looks like the person who wrote the notes got mixed up in the notation.  $1-\beta$ usually refers to statistical power, hence $\beta$ should be the % of type 2 errors you can expect when running many simulations. See the second paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics). The value between parenthesis seems to be the distribution mean (0.5), i.e. I'd interpret the notation as "a power of 0.95 given a mean of 0.5".

A good exercise would be to find for which value of $\sigma$ you can get a power of 0.95, given an alpha of 0.05, a mean of 0.5, and a sample size of 500.

Thank you for your effort and advice. Ok. But the question is written for $\sigma > 0$

Yes, but there's a value of $\sigma > 0$ that can give you a power of 0.95. You chose to give a value of 5 to $\sigma$ in your simulation, which gave you a power of about 0.63. However, nothing in the original notes says $\sigma$ should be specifically equal to 5, so you can change it for something else.

@J-J-J Understood. Thank you.  Programatically this is easy to achieve. But that is nothing one can do in a simple "true-false-task".

Your t-test is calculating a p-value for a sample from a population where the mean is 0.5 and the standard deviation is 5. You are testing the null hypothesis that the mean in the population is zero.
You cannot make a type I error. A type I error is the probability of obtaining a result when the null hypothesis is true. The null hypothesis is not true.
If you find a significant result, you (correctly) reject the null hypothesis. If you do not, you fail to reject the null hypothesis and make a type II error. Sorry, but I don't understand 2 and 3.
However, you seem to be doing a simulation to estimate power.
You can do this with the power.t.test() function and get an exact result with probaiblity $a$.
Make the mean 0 (i.e. rnorm(500, 0, 5) and you should obtain a statistically significant result
power.t.test(type = "one.sample", delta = 0.5, n = 500, sd = 5)

Gives me:

     One-sample t test power calculation 

              n = 500
          delta = 0.5
             sd = 5
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.6071117
    alternative = two.sided

Compare with:
iter = 10000
n = 500
# alpha, beta
a = .05 # b(0.5) = .95 (given in the question)
set.seed(1)
replicate(iter, t.test(rnorm(500, .5, 5))$p.value < a) |> sum()

Which gives me 6051 (or 0.6051, pretty close to 0.6071 that I get from power.t.test()).
Sometimes there is no function to estimate power, and then you need to (as you have) do a simulation.

Thank you! I can follow to the point that any one sided test is used to compare the true mean to something. Well, the question is exactly asked like that. I cannot change to $\mu=0$ I guess.

Why can't you change my to zero? Wouldn't that be rnorm(500, 0, 5)? Maybe3i don't understand, sorry.
